# CSS calc does not work when subtracting from percentage [Opera]

Tags: css, opera, css-calc

A: `width: calc((100% - SOME_INTEGER_NUMBERpx) / 2)`

B: `width: calc((100%) / 2)`

Original style rule of the element is A. When inspecting element with DEV tools (Opera)  A style is not marked as invalid but it does not work either.

When changing calc expression to look like B (via DEV tools) element looks as expected.

**Update 1**:
As you can see the bowser likes the expression: it is parsed and is not being overriden
[image]

**Update 2**:

Must be an issue of Opera 60.0.3255.151 since other browsers apply CSS rule as expected. Will try another version of Opera and will report shortly. Thx @Ry

**Update 3**:
Same issue when browsing with Opera 58.0.3135.132. Sadly a hack (`calc(100% / 2 - 55px / 2)`) suggested by someone whose comment/answer is no longer visible does not work either. **Issue must be web-app connected**

Comment: share full code so we can see that it's not working

Comment: @TemaniAfif your answer in the duplicate question i think is the answer for this question.

Comment: @Sfili_81 the duplicate is about missing spaces which is not the case here.

Comment: @TemaniAfif i've read better, and it's my bad sorry, i think he miss the nested calc like this _calc( calc(100% - 20px) / 2 )_ but it isn't this case. sorry again.

Comment: @TemanAfif what about cross-browser compatibility of using simple parenthesis? I didn't even know that simple parenthesis could be used inside `calc`. I guess you learn something new everyday.

Comment: I’m curious of whether `calc(50% - 27.5px)` works. Also, which version of Opera? Did you try any other browsers?

Comment: I tried `width: calc( ( 100% - 51px ) / 2 );` in chromium just now and it worked just fine.

Comment: Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/d084pcrm/. I will probably have to dig deep into inner elements but it still bugs me that subtraction intoduces this behaviour

Comment: Guess what: in IE it works as expected:D

Comment: @Ry introducing decimal point does not help. Using the up-to date Opera

Comment: @user435421: Which version of Opera? Did you try any other browsers?

Comment: @AayushSharma if a browser support calc() it also support simple parenthesis. Simple parenthesis is not a feature, it's a valid syntax of CSS calc() : https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-syntax